# At cloud foundry healthcheck, "[HEALTH / 0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/ health' on port 8080: received status code 404 in 0ms"

Tags: cloud-foundry

[problem]
Is it possible to output "port 8080" in this error log as "port 80"?

[procedure]

```
$ cf push
$ cf set-health-check <myapp> --endpoint / health
$ cf logs <myapp>
-
  [HEALTH / 0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/ health' on port 8080: received status code 404 in 0ms
  [CELL / 0] ERR Timed out after 10m0s: health check never passed.
-
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo in one of your commands. There is a space between `/` and `health` in the `cf set-health-check` command. That appears to be injecting a space into the URL that's used by the health check, so it's trying to reach the literal URL `/%20health`, which doesn't exist, hence the 404 response.

Try `cf set-health-check <myapp> --endpoint "/health"` and see if that works.

Sorry, not sure about this question.

> Is it possible to output "port 8080" in this error log as "port 80"?

Your app seems to be listening on the correct port, as there's a 404 which means something is listening and responding. Port 8080 is also the correct port for Cloud Foundry apps on which 99.9% of time your app should be listening so I wouldn't try to change that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Is there no way to check health with port80?
Because the app is waiting on port80.

Comment: If this is a buildpack app, no. The platform is going to assign you a port and you need to listen on that. It does look like something is listening on port 8080 though. Does your app listen on that port too? If you're deploying a Docker container, you have some control over the port that's picked. Diego will pick the first port it finds exposed from your image and use that.

Comment: Actually, that's not 100% true with buildpack apps. If you're on a new enough version of Cloud Foundry, there's support for this. I believe support was added around April 2019, so versions after that should support it. You can see the docs here. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html It does require some `cf curl`'ing so the user experience is a little rough at the moment. Maybe something to try and see if your provider supports it.

Comment: To Daniel
Thank you for reply.
This case seems to be closed.